# Multiple variables in PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, function

I looked around but couldnt find what i looked for so i thought i should try and ask.

Also i should mention i am quite new to most codes.

I am trying to get multiple variables from my database into my function.
From here i need the image link and the id. (As you can see i tried to link them in the onclick=)

```
<div id="HeadItems" >

<?php
$sqlhead = "SELECT * FROM items
WHERE part = 'head'";
$headquery = mysqli_query($con, $sqlhead) or die (mysqli_error($con));  

while($headf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($headquery))
{
?>
    <img class="headArmor" src="<?php echo $headf['image']; ?>" onclick="headHide('<?php echo $headf['image']; ?>", "<?php echo $headf['id']; ?>')"/>
<?php
}
?>

</div>
```

They go into my function:

```
function headHide(src, chosenid) {
    var head = document.getElementById("head");
    var HeadItems = document.getElementById('HeadItems');
    HeadItems.style.display = 'none';
    head.innerHTML = "<img src='" +src+ "' width=80; height=80;>";
    var chosenhead = chosenid;

}
```

(when i click on the image the image is then inserted into the head.innerHTML)
Problem is that after i put in the second variable in the function (chosenid and the $headf['id'] in the while loop) it stopped working.

I probably made it hard to understand now (I'm dutch) so a small summary:

I want my onclick function to give me the $headf['head'] and $headf['id'].
so i can make the $headf['id'] into a var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some single quotes missing here:

```
onclick="headHide('<?php echo $headf['image']; ?>', '<?php echo $headf['id']; ?>')"
                                                 ^  ^
```

Comment: Also the double quotes next to them should be removed.

Comment: I hate it when that happens! Thanks :)

Comment: i think i needed to change that too but it still doesn't work (Unexpected token ILLEGAL) i probably just made a stupid mistake somewhere
Removed the double quotes now too.
You guys rule!

Comment: Illegal what? There must be more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes in the definition of onclick.
This should work.

```
onclick="headHide(<?php echo '\''.$headf['image'].'\',\''.$headf['id'].'\''; ?>)"
//This will be onclick="headHide('image','id')"
```